# Recently "exposed" to Clicksor

Tags: virus, malware, trojan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virus…? Tons of people talking. Not sure where else to ask.](https://superuser.com/questions/240985/virus-tons-of-people-talking-not-sure-where-else-to-ask)

Previous information concerning my issue can be found here:

[Virus...? Tons of people talking. Not sure where else to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/240985/virus-tons-of-people-talking-not-sure-where-else-to-ask)

I heard the loud sounds and whatnot from one of the ads but nothing was harmed and other than having the life scared out of me nothing was immediately affected. Literally nothing has changed. I really don't know what to do. My PC seems fine and from what Malwarebytes and Spybot tells me none of my files have been infected with anything. If you need more information I will be glad to supply it. Thanks in advance.

Malwarebytes quick and full scan: Clean.

Spybot S&D scan: Clean.

HijackThis log:

```
Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.4
Scan saved at 5:23:33 PM, on 2/2/2011
Platform: Windows 7  (WinNT 6.00.3504)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v8.00 (8.00.7600.16700)
Boot mode: Normal

Running processes:
C:\Program Files (x86)\DeviceVM\Browser Configuration Utility\BCU.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\NEC Electronics\USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver\Application\nusb3mon.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\UpdateService\issch.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe
C:\Fraps\fraps.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugin-container.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Trend Micro\HiJackThis\HiJackThis.exe

R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,SearchAssistant = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch = 
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Local Page = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\blank.htm
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
R3 - URLSearchHook: SearchHook Class - {BC86E1AB-EDA5-4059-938F-CE307B0C6F0A} - C:\Program Files (x86)\DeviceVM\Browser Configuration Utility\AddressBarSearch.dll
F2 - REG:system.ini: UserInit=userinit.exe
O2 - BHO: AcroIEHelperStub - {18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelperShim.dll
O2 - BHO: Windows Live ID Sign-in Helper - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper - {DBC80044-A445-435b-BC74-9C25C1C588A9} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [BCU] "C:\Program Files (x86)\DeviceVM\Browser Configuration Utility\BCU.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [JMB36X IDE Setup] C:\Windows\RaidTool\xInsIDE.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [NUSB3MON] "C:\Program Files (x86)\NEC Electronics\USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver\Application\nusb3mon.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [ISUSScheduler] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\UpdateService\issch.exe" -start
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [ISUSPM Startup] C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\UPDATE~1\ISUSPM.exe -startup
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe Reader Speed Launcher] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe ARM] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\RunOnce: [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware] C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\mbamgui.exe /install /silent
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [ISUSPM Startup] C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\UPDATE~1\ISUSPM.exe -startup
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [Sidebar] %ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\Sidebar.exe /autoRun (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\RunOnce: [mctadmin] C:\Windows\System32\mctadmin.exe (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O10 - Unknown file in Winsock LSP: c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidnsp.dll
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\Alg.exe,-112 (ALG) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: AppleChargerSrv - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\AppleChargerSrv.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Browser Configuration Utility Service (BCUService) - DeviceVM, Inc. - C:\Program Files (x86)\DeviceVM\Browser Configuration Utility\BCUService.exe
O23 - Service: DES2 Service for Energy Saving. (DES2 Service) - Unknown owner - C:\Program Files (x86)\GIGABYTE\EnergySaver2\des2svr.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\efssvc.dll,-100 (EFS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\fxsresm.dll,-118 (Fax) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\fxssvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: InstallDriver Table Manager (IDriverT) - Macrovision Corporation - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InstallShield\Driver\11\Intel 32\IDriverT.exe
O23 - Service: JMB36X - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\XSrvSetup.exe
O23 - Service: @keyiso.dll,-100 (KeyIso) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @comres.dll,-2797 (MSDTC) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\System32\netlogon.dll,-102 (Netlogon) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: NVIDIA Driver Helper Service (NVSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\nvvsvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\psbase.dll,-300 (ProtectedStorage) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\Locator.exe,-2 (RpcLocator) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\locator.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\samsrv.dll,-1 (SamSs) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\snmptrap.exe,-3 (SNMPTRAP) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\snmptrap.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\spoolsv.exe,-1 (Spooler) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe,-101 (sppsvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\sppsvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: Steam Client Service - Valve Corporation - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe
O23 - Service: NVIDIA Stereoscopic 3D Driver Service (Stereo Service) - NVIDIA Corporation - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvSCPAPISvr.exe
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\ui0detect.exe,-101 (UI0Detect) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\UI0Detect.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vaultsvc.dll,-1003 (VaultSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vds.exe,-100 (vds) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\vds.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\vssvc.exe,-102 (VSS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\vssvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\Wat\WatUX.exe,-601 (WatAdminSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\Wat\WatAdminSvc.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\wbengine.exe,-104 (wbengine) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbengine.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%Systemroot%\system32\wbem\wmiapsrv.exe,-110 (wmiApSrv) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbem\WmiApSrv.exe (file missing)
O23 - Service: @%PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe,-101 (WMPNetworkSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe (file missing)

--
End of file - 7889 bytes
```

Comment: If this is extra info for your previous post, you should edit your original question and add it there. You've also accepted an answer in your previous post so you are sending out mixed messages about whether you have or haven't fixed the issue??

Comment: Accepted an answer as a diagnosis, not a fix. You scrolled right past a HijackThis log.

Comment: Firstly, @Linker3000 is right, and you should have modified your original question. Secondly, I don't see anything suspicious in the log you posted. What exactly is the status of the problem?

Comment: I was told to make a new post by another user helping me in the previous question. Yell at him not me, I'm just looking for help and following what someone just like you told me to do. Is there a Stack Exchange hivemind I'm supposed to be a part of to avoid this sort of endeavor? The status of the "problem" is, well, fine. I'm just looking for confirmation that I'm in the clear and that there's most likely nothing to worry about.

Comment: Like I said on the other question if everything looks good it probably is. However there is always a small chance something slipped through and no one can 100% assure you there is no malware without a reformat. The Malware makers are quite clever and always a step ahead of security experts, the very nature of the business dictates this. I meant you should ask another question if you need help implementing a specific fix. Posting Hijack this logs and that virus scans came out clean will yield you the same answer you got on the first question.

Comment: You simply misunderstood me, it happens, I don't think anyone will hold it against you.